# Keeping the older values of Inner repeaters

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, repeater, ascx

I am having two nested repeaters whose code are on two separate aspx pages and the parent repeater has a button on each row. On the button click, the inner repeater gets called and loaded.

Also, the data for both repeaters are getting loaded by execution of the stored procedures.

So now, for example if I click the button on the second row of the parent repeater the inner inner child repeater gets displayed. But then if I click the first row of the parent repeater, the inner child repeater for that row gets displayed but the already loaded values for the second row gets disappeared.

How can I keep the already loaded values of the inner child repeater with new click of button on each time?

//Parent repeater code

```
 protected void rptCoverage_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "CoverageDetails")
        {
            //changing the button to '-'
            var btn = e.Item.FindControl("btnShowCoveragedetails") as Button;
            var policy = e.Item.FindControl("lblPolicyNo") as Label;
            var description = e.Item.FindControl("lblDescription") as Label;
            var idPerson = id_person;

            if (btn.Text == "+")
            {
                btn.Text = "-";
            }
            else
            {
                btn.Text = "+";
            }

            Session["idPerson"] = idPerson;
            Session["policy"] = policy.Text.Trim();
            Session["description"] = description.Text.Trim();


            var placeHolder = e.Item.FindControl("UCPlaceHolder") as Control;

            placeHolder.Controls.Add((PolicyDetailsTemplate1)Page.LoadControl("~/Shared/Controls/PolicyDetailsTemplate1.ascx")); 

            //check to see if the template was loaded earlier
            //var tempalte = placeHolder.FindControl("")


        }
    }
```

//Child Inner repeater Code

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CustomerPortalWebContentEntities context = new CustomerPortalWebContentEntities();
        RetrievePolicyDetails policyDetails = new RetrievePolicyDetails();
        List<PolicyDetails> polDetails = policyDetails.GetPolicyDetails((string)Session["idPerson"], (string)Session["policy"], (string)Session["description"]);

        rptPolicyDetails.DataSource = polDetails;
        rptPolicyDetails.DataBind();

        Session.Clear();

    }
```

//OUTPUT snippet
[image: Inner Repeater on first button click]
[image: Inner Repeater on Second button click]

Basically, how can I keep the data on the inner child repeater loaded on each new button click?